# how to scrape javascript web site?

Tags: python, api, scrapy

Hello everyone I'm a beginner at scraping and i try to scrape all iPhones in https://www.electroplanet.ma/
this is the scripts i wrote

```
import scrapy 
from ..items import EpItem


class ep(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ep"
    start_urls = ["https://www.electroplanet.ma/smartphone-tablette-gps/smartphone/iphone?p=1",
    "https://www.electroplanet.ma/smartphone-tablette-gps/smartphone/iphone?p=2"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        products = response.css("ol li")  # to find all items in the page
        for product in products :
            try:
                lien = product.css("a.product-item-link::attr(href)").get() # get the link of each item
                image= product.css("a.product-item-photo::attr(href)").get()  # get the image

               # and to get in each item page and scrap it, i use follow method
               # i passed image as argument to parse_item cauz i couldn't scrap the image from item's page
               # i think it's hidden
                yield response.follow(lien,callback = self.parse_item,cb_kwargs={"image":image}) 
            except: pass     

    def parse_item(self,response,image):
        item = EpItem()
        item["Nom"]= response.css(".ref::text").get()
        pattern = re.compile(r"\s*(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*)\s*")
        item["Catégorie"]= pattern.search(response.xpath("//h1/a/text()").get()).group(1)
        item["Marque"]=pattern.search(response.xpath("//*[@data-th='Marque']/text()").get()).group(1)
        try :
          item["RAM"]= pattern.search(response.xpath("//*[@data-th='MÉMOIRE RAM']/text()").get()).group(1)
        except:
            pass
        item["ROM"]=pattern.search(response.xpath("//*[@data-th='MÉMOIRE DE STOCKAGE']/text()").get()).group(1)
        item["Couleur"]=pattern.search(response.xpath("//*[@data-th='COULEUR']/text()").get()).group(1)
        item["lien"]=response.request.url
        item["image"]=image
        item["état"]="neuf"
        item["Market"]= "Electro Planet"
        yield item
```

i found problems to scrape all the pages, because it uses javascript to follow pages so i write all pages links in start urls and i believe it's not the best practice so i ask you to give some advices to improve my code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use the [scrapy-playwright](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright) plugin to scrape the interactive websites, and for the start_urls, just add the main website index URL if there is just one website, and check this [link](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links) in the scrapy docs to make the spider follow the pages links automatically instead of written them manually

Comment: the problem is the next_page button is hidden i couldn't find it using scrapy nor scrapy + playwright and I don't know why

Comment: oh now it works using spider automatically follow pages method  thanks for your help

Comment: kindly if my answer was helpful to you  remove the "this answer is not helpful"  that you gave to my answer

Comment: it's not me, cause i need at least 15 reputations to cast a vote